# A SQL query to select until SUM(users_count) reaches 1000

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I need a sql query to select rows from my messages queue, until SUM(users_count) reaches at most 1000. **BUT** there is no problem if there be only one row returned and that row's users_count is greater than 1000.

I need something like: (i added my own keywords)

```
SELECT * FROM `messages_queue` UNTIL SUM(users_count) < 1000 AT LEAST 1 ROW
```

This is my table structure:

> messages_queue
>     - msg_id
>     - msg_body
>     - users_count (number of message recieptors)
>     - time (insert time)

Comment: What does the `users_count` column represent?

Comment: If you want to select rows, how should there be a SUM of one value in one row. Please be more specific.

Comment: what is your desired ordering? i.e. what records take precedence in determining what to include first in your running sum?

Comment: `users_count` represents count of users that i must send this message to. the only thing that is important here is that i want to control the traffic, and send messages in parallel if one of them had 2,000,000 receptors (users_count) it will be a long queue, so its better to send messages in parallel.

Comment: i have a `time` column and ordering must be on this column. (first in first out)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Select "until"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287333/sql-select-until)

Comment: So what you want is really to cycle, from oldest record forward, in increments where your total sum of users_count, across those records is up to a  certain threshold?  This seems like a problem that would be better suited for the application side.

Comment: @dmcnelis yeah i have a certain threshold. its only because the server that im sending messages to is limited to receive only 100 messages in minute, so i don't want a huge send (like a 50,000) stops other little sends (like 5 or 4) in queue. i want them to send in parallel. (40 msg/min for that 50,000 and 60 msg/min for other little sends). SO SORRY for my poor english, its not my native lang.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This solution will perform a cumulative sum, stopping when the sum exceeds 1000:

```
SELECT NULL AS users_count, NULL AS total
  FROM dual
 WHERE (@total := 0)
 UNION
SELECT users_count, @total := @total + users_count AS total
  FROM messages_queue
 WHERE @total < 1000;
```

That means that if you have two values of, say, 800, the sum total will be 1600.  The first SELECT is just to initialise the `@total` variable.

If you want to prevent the sum from exceeding 1000, apart from in cases where a single row has a value of greater than 1000, then I think this works, although you'll need to subject it to some rigorous testing:

```
SELECT NULL AS users_count, NULL AS total, NULL AS found
  FROM dual
 WHERE (@total := 0 OR @found := 0)
 UNION
SELECT users_count, @total AS total, @found := 1 AS found
  FROM messages_queue
 WHERE (@total := @total + users_count)
   AND @total < 1000
 UNION
SELECT users_count, users_count AS total, 0 AS found
  FROM messages_queue
 WHERE IF(@found = 0, @found := 1, 0);
```

Comment: WOW, thanks @Mike, i need a lot of time to analyze your very good query, i'm a beginner. i will benchmark your and other people answers, to see which one is faster on my table.

Comment: @Aram Alipoor: It's worth mentioning that this will only work in MySQL, as it uses MySQL variables.  You can find more information in this great article: [Advanced MySQL user variable techniques](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/).

Comment: You are brilliant Mike thank you for the query, it works like a charm. and thanks for the article too, i needed it from a long time ago.

Comment: @Mike: Your solution works perfectly fine for MySQL. I have a SQL parser engine which adheres with SQL standard and I am finding really difficult to do it there. How would you write this query in SQL standard? I would love to hear from you.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to add this as a comment to Mike's answer, however, it is problematic with the @ signs for variables.

To draw on Mike's answer, the query could actually be made shorter by initializing the variable in the FROM clause, e.g.:

```
SELECT users_count, @total := @total + users_count AS total
    FROM (messages_queue, (select @total := 0) t)
WHERE @total < 1000;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   (SELECT 
        *
      , (select sum(users_count) from `messages_queue` where time <= mq.time) RunningTotal       
   FROM `messages_queue` mq) mq2
WHERE mq2.RunningTotal < 1000
```

Comment: if the table has much data , you will get a very, very slow statement:
The inner select has no limit, so it will make a full table scan, depending on the table size this must be done on disk. But in general, it could work.

Comment: @Thomas Berger - Not sure how smart the MySql optimizer is, but it will probably result in a full table scan

Comment: i must say that my table have at most 200 rows. because in every call i will delete sent messages rows. thank you so much @Aducci

Answer (score 2):

Kudos to Aducci for the pure SQL solution, but as Thomas Berger said, this could end up being a very expensive query. Depending on the size of your table a stored procedure could well be the better approach:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE messages_to_send
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE oldest_date DATETIME;
  DECLARE cur_count INT;
  DECLARE que_size INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT users_count, time FROM messages_que ORDER BY time;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN curs;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH curs INTO cur_count, oldest_date;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    que_size = que_size + cur_count
    IF que_size >= 1000
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE curs

  SELECT * FROM messages_que WHERE time < oldest_date;
END

CALL messages_to_send(); --> returns a result set of messages to send with a total user_count of 1000 or less
```

Comment: this is amazing, thank you @ChrisBailey so much for your effort. i will benchmark your answer and Aducci's one, to see which one is faster on my table.

Comment: After some testing i found that your stored proc is needed whenever my table get bigger. so its better to use Mike's query, because there will be at most 200 rows in my table.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you could to this with a simple MySQL Query.

You will have to use a stored procedure or filter that in your application.

**EDIT**

I'm no MySQL Guru (could only code stored procedures on oracle and postgres) but you could start here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-cursor-in-stored-procedures.aspx .

More general informations about the syntax is located here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: I think you're right, can you provide me with a stored procedure, because i never write any stored proc before. thank you

Comment: Edited my Answer, but you could have a look at the answer from @Aducci