# How can I write an UPDATE query for this SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a query from my previous question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097413/an-sql-query-to-select-until-sumusers-count-reaches-1000)) about a complex select,
and my question is, how can I write an update query for result of this query, to change fet_id to some new value.

Note that this query will select rows from a queue until rcpts_count reaches 1000, (for traffic controlling). more information about this query is, [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097413/an-sql-query-to-select-until-sumusers-count-reaches-1000)

```
   SELECT NULL AS msg_id, NULL AS total, NULL AS found
    FROM dual
     WHERE (
      @total :=0
       OR 
      @found :=0
    )
    UNION
      SELECT msg_id, @total AS total, @found :=1 AS found
        FROM messages_queue
      WHERE (
        @total := @total + rcpts_count
      )
    AND @total <1000
    UNION
      SELECT msg_id, rcpts_count AS total, 0 AS found
        FROM messages_queue
      WHERE IF( @found =0, @found :=1, 0 )
```

Comment: Are you wanting to update all records within the set returned with the above table, setting the field 'fet_id' to a single value for the entire set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to update all the records within the set, you could write a query like this:

```
UPDATE message_queue mq
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT NULL AS msg_id, NULL AS total, NULL AS found
    FROM dual
     WHERE (
      @total :=0
       OR 
      @found :=0
    )
    UNION
      SELECT msg_id, @total AS total, @found :=1 AS found
        FROM messages_queue
      WHERE (
        @total := @total + rcpts_count
      )
      AND @total <1000
    UNION
      SELECT msg_id, rcpts_count AS total, 0 AS found
      FROM messages_queue
      WHERE IF( @found =0, @found :=1, 0 )
) msgs ON msgs.msg_id = mq.msg_id
SET mq.fet_id = 12345;
```

However, depending on your activity, this isn't a safe approach, as the records returned from the query could change between the two requests.

I would recommend one of the following approaches:

- Handle the updates on the application side
- Create a temporary table with the result of the query, and update the table with a join to the temporary table
- Assuming 'fet_id' is a key unique to this batch, run the update statement first, then do a simple select based on fet_id.

Comment: Thank you @DougKress i must mention that this table won't have any `UPDATE`, just `INSERT` then `SELECT` then `DELETE`. So in my situation you suggest run your (unsafe) query?

Comment: I'm confused about your question - in what you're trying to update (you asked 'how can I write an update query') with the result of the data. Is there another table you'd like to update? Would you like to delete said records after performing the select?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are asking for MySql. This is an MsSql solution, but I think the syntax is really close (but not 100% sure of that). This sample is simplified so it can apply to any Stack user. Hopefully, you can translate to your specific dataset.

```
-- sample table
create table x 
    (col1 int identity(1, 1)
    ,col2 varchar(50))

-- sample data  
insert into x (col2) values
     (null)
    ,(null)
    ,(null)
    ,(null)
    ,(null)

-- update from select
update x
    set x.col2 = 'even'
from x as [t2]
where 
    col1 = t2.col1
    and t2.col1 % 2 = 0

-- show results
select * from x

-- clean up
drop table x
```

Best of luck.