# Select rows until column sum reaches a value

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with file names and numbers of entries in them. I'd like to select the first `N` files such that the sum of the numbers of their entries is greater then or equal to `M`, but is less then `M` for `N-1` files.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7097413/2640636), but it appears to not work for `sqlite3`. I get `Error: unrecognized token: ":"`.

Comment: Aducci's answer will work, but is horribly slow. Is it really necessary to do everything in SQL?

Comment: @CL. I already solved this in python. I was just wondering if there's a good way to do this in `sqlite`. After all, it seems like something not uncommon.