# Stop SQL Select After Sum Reached

Tags: sql, sum, ibm-midrange, db2-400

My database is Db2 for IBM i.

I have read-only access, so my query must use only basic SQL select commands.

==============================================================

**Goal:**

I want to select every record in the table until the sum of the amount column exceeds the predetermined limit.

**Example:**

I want to match every item down the table until the sum of matched values in the "price" column >= $9.00.

[image]

**The desired result:**

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A SQL query to select until SUM(users\_count) reaches 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097413/a-sql-query-to-select-until-sumusers-count-reaches-1000)

Comment: @Zak - Not really. MySQL is different enough from Db2 for i that solutions for one often don't apply to the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `sum` analytic function to calculate running total of price and then filter by its value:

> ```
> with a as (
>   select
>     t.*,
>     sum(price) over(order by salesid asc) as price_rsum
>   from t
> )
> select *
> from a
> where price_rsum <= 9
> ```
>
> ```
> SALESID | PRICE | PRICE_RSUM
> ------: | ----: | ---------:
>    1001 |     5 |          5
>    1002 |     3 |          8
>    1003 |     1 |          9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=148bcb905a9e4118bf07593d544b6ee8)*

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer.

This got me what I needed - for my own understanding, do you know why we have to append "t." to the "*" in the with(select) section of the statement? I tried it without the "t." and it didn't work.

Comment: @LoganPrice I actually do not know, this is the syntax rule. Some databases allow star along with other expressions in the select list, others does not and require table alias in front of it. I usually put an alias every time because of this difference

Comment: Ok, as long as it works I'm good.

There is one quirk I can't seem to work out with your solution. For some reason, the query assigns the running total to records from newest to oldest. Even when I change the order by in the WITH clause and even if I do a nested SELECT with ORDER BY within the WITH clause.

I would rather it assign the running total from oldest to newest. Do you know why this is happening and how to change it?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. I added a nested SELECT clause to the WITH clause. Within that nested SELECT, I sorted the date columns ascending. In the WITH, OVER clause, I sorted ascending. It works perfectly now! Thank you!

Comment: @LoganPrice Analytic function used with `order by` in the `over` clause becomes a window function that performs calculation on a subset of rows in a group, defined by `partition by`. If no window is specified, then calculation is performed on all the rows from the start of partition and up to the current row according to the `order by`. So to start from the oldest records, you need to specify `desc` order: `over(order by salesid desc)`